# Getting warning when kept multiple make files in same directory

Tags: python, makefile

make files are new for me. I have kept multiple make files under same directory. Directory structure is like,

```
tt\
   a\
   b\
   c\
   common\
   a.build.mk
   b.build.mk
   c.build.mk
```

where each files has text like,

```
name := a_tests
lang := python

python_files := $(shell find $(def_path)/tt/ -name "*.py")
source := $(subst $(def_path)/, ,$(python_files))

generation_dep := dep dep1

python_files :=
```

in other files everything is same except name and generation_dep. So for b.build.mk will have `name := b_tests` and `generation_dep := dep dep2`

Problem I am facing is getting following warning,
**"tools/gmake/python.mk:37: warning: ignoring old commands for target 'some-file-path'"**

Please let me know how I can get rid of this warning.

Comment: How are you specifying which makefile to use?

Comment: If I have to build files for a_tests then I do "make a_tests"

Comment: You need to specify the makefile to use: `make -f a.build.mk a_tests`

Comment: I don't understand how those makefiles are being used. By default, make just looks for `makefile` or `Makefile`, not `*.build.mk`. Do you have a main makefile with `include *.build.mk` in it?

Comment: In my environment I never had to use file name. Just use name specified in the make file. As I am new with make, not sure what is expected here.

Comment: I still don't understand how these `*.build.mk` files are getting used. There's nothing that uses them by default, so you must have something that's adding them.

Comment: And the problem is that you're merging all of them into your `makefile`, but there's lots of duplication between them. You should put all the common parts into a single makefile, and just use `xxx.build.mk` for the things that are specific to that name.

Comment: As you mentioned I made one single file for common part and modified other files to keep only specific part. This solved the problem.

Comment: So problem was caused as in all the files there was repetitive part which was complaining. Thanks.

Comment: You should post what you did as an answer, so it will help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning was coming because of repetitive part from multiple .mk file.
To solve the issue I moved repetitive part from all mk files to the common.build.mk file and kept only specific part in individual mk files.

Comment: Guess it would help if you add some more details

Answer (score 0):

A meta-answer: consider that you might be over-complicating this.

The usual pattern is for there to be one makefile per directory, named the default `Makefile`; that's a *good* pattern, which should be deviated from only with positive good reason. If you want to get fancy (typically documentation and tests are in different directories), then you might have multiple makefiles collaborating, but you do that via a rule such as `cd subdir; $(MAKE)`.  Using `include` to pull in other fragments, such as rules or common definitions *might* be a simplification, but may also be an indication that your code is spread out too much (specifically, tightly coupled code should often be in a single directory).

There are no hard and fast rules here, but for me, a complicated build process is a code smell.  The `make` system implements a simple language, and that's a good thing; like many simple languages, it gets really messy really quickly if you don't work to keep things as simple as possible.

(The immediate answer to your question may be that `:=` is generally for things that are set once and not intended to be overridden, unlike `=`.  If you do override such a setting, you'll get such a warning.)